# Weird bug on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When inside the window part of eclipse, the letter "r" on my keyboard stop working. Elsewhere in the editor the letter work, even when keybinding and naming of classes in Java.

And it also make some other combination to stop as well. When I press on the r letter, together with e and n it stop working.

I have tried to go to keybinding and reconfigure it back to default.
It is possible to use the r, but not alone. I can even type a big R with Shift-r, but no only press the r.

I use Ubuntu 18.4

Any suggestion?

Comment: On which OS do you observe this issue?

Comment: What operating system? I vaguely recall something about the Mac OS, though not with these specifics.

Comment: Does it mean that you cannot type "r" when writing code? Or, does it not work when using a combination (like CTRL-R)?

Comment: Did you restart the device already? :P

Comment: Yes. I have rebooted twice after changing the in preferances.

Comment: Changing the *what*?